# Store reads, but the store.records.length is always 0

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.SensorStation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {

                name: 'name', 
                type: 'string',
                mapping: '@name'
                //convert: function (value, record) {
                //    Ext.Msg.alert(value,record.raw);
                //    //var nodes = rec.raw.querySelectorAll('');
                //}
            },
            {
                name: 'lat',
                mapping: '@latitude',
                type: 'float'
            },
            {
                name: 'lng',
                mapping: '@longitude',
                type: 'float'
            },
            {
                name: 'locid',
                mapping:'@locid',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/configuration',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record:'locations',
            rootProperty: 'nmts'
        }
    }
});



Ext.define('myApp.store.SensorStationStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['myApp.model.SensorStation'],
    config:{
        model: 'myApp.model.SensorStation',
        storeId: 'SensorStore'
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.define('myApp.controller.SensorStations', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],
    config: {
        refs: {
            mapComponent: 'main map'
        },
        control: {
            mapComponent: {
                maprender: 'onMaprender'
            }
        }
    },


    onMaprender: function (mapComponent, googleMap) {
        var store, latlng, marker;


        // Use Store name when testing on devices
        // Use Store ID when testing in browsers
        var sensorStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('SensorStore');
        if (!sensorStore) {
            console.log("Store not found");
            Ext.Msg.alert('error', "store not found");
            return;
        }
        //else {
        //    console.log("Store found");
        //    Ext.Msg.alert('great', "store found");
        //    //return;
        //}


        sensorStore.load({
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {

                mapComponent.setMapOptions({
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.899328, 144.843333)
                });


                if (success) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('success', records);
                }
                else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('error', operation);
                }


                Ext.Msg.alert('records.count = ' + records.length, 'haha');



            }
        });




    }


});
```

The records.length is always 0.
Could you please point out where I get wrong?

Also I'd like to know the data structure of the records.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post the xml that is returned from the server?

Comment: hmm, I don't see that the xml reader should have a 'rootProperty' config. It should be 'root'

Comment: hi @AmitAviv really thank you for your reply. but I saw the document which uses rootProperty. from where did you see it's root? Btw, I have tried to use "root", still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using sencha touch.. thought it was extjs

Comment: hi @AmitAviv here is the xml file http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/configuration

Answer (score 0):

In your model put the `proxy: {}` inside `config:{}` and in store put `autoload: true`inside `config:{}`

Comment: Hi Naitik, I have tried it as well. Still got no luck. Any other ideas? thank you :)